# how can I stop r devtools::check() from noting .DS_Store

Tags: r, devtools

Every time I run `devtools::check()` on my package it throws a note about:

```
> checking for non-standard things in the check directory ... NOTE
  Found the following files/directories:
    ‘.DS_Store’
```

My .Rbuildignore includes:

```
^.*\.Rproj$
^\.Rproj\.user$
^\.DS_Store$
```

How can I tell the `check()` to ignore the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I restarted RStudio and it fixed itself.    I have no idea why it didn't notice the changes in .Rbuildignore after the file was saved. I had saved and restarted the R session.

Comment: Same thing happened to me: the `check()` ignores the file only when I completely re-launch RStudio.  A simple in-session restart doesn't work.

Comment: Restarting RStudio worked for me too.